# Set Theorem Exercise (String Recognizer/Russell's Paradox)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question summarizes to be:

- Define a string procedure P, that given a string s, it returns a boolean. P recognizes s if P(s) returns true.
- Associate every string s with a procedure Ps. Namely, a total function f that maps s to f(s), where f(s) is the set of strings Ps can recognize.
- Now define a set N ::= {s ∈ string | s ∉ f(s)}, prove that N is not recognizable.

The question hint says it is similar to Russell's paradox, and I know that you're supposed to assume s is recognizable by some procedure Pw, so that s ∉ f(s) AND s ∈ f(w), then set s = w and reach the contradiction.

But I am confused about why you must set s to w. I read N ::= {s ∈ string | s ∉ f(s)} as a set of strings that can't recognize itself. Can't there be a string w outside of N that recognizes elements in N? Thank you.

([question source](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/104426/6-042j-spring-2010/contents/lecture-notes/MIT6_042JS10_lec08_prob.pdf); [solution source](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/104426/6-042j-spring-2010/contents/lecture-notes/MIT6_042JS10_lec08_sol.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

There are just two possibilities: either $w\in N$, or $w\notin N$.

- If $w\in N$, then by the definition of $N$ we know that $w\notin f(w)$. This means that $P_w$ cannot recognize $w$, and that’s impossible: on the one hand $P_w$ recognizes the strings in $N$ and therefore recognizes $w$, but on the other hand $P_w$ does not recognize $w$.
- If $w\notin N$, then by the definition of $N$ we know that $w\in f(w)$, which means that $P_w$ can recognize $w$. But **that** means that $w\in N$, and again we have a contradiction.

Since we get a contradiction either way, there simply cannot be any such string $w$. That is, there is no procedure $P_w$ that recognizes $N$.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you so much! I also wonder if "N is recognizable" means every string in N is recognizable, and if it means there exists a single procedure P (as opposed to multiple procedures) to recognize all strings in N.

Comment: @Fores: ‘$N$ is recognizable’ means that there is a single string procedure $P$ that returns `True` for a string if and only if that string is in $N$.